# AVQueuePlayer stops streaming in background (Terminate due to signal 9)

Tags: objective-c, memory, background, stream, avqueueplayer

I am developing an app, which streams music from soundcloud. For this, I am using the AVQueuePlayer initialized with several AVPlayerItems. Everything works fine, until the app enters the background. It takes 1-2 minutes, then the playback stops and I get XCode debugging error code "Terminate due to signal 9". I looked up the memory and the app constantly needs ~25MB of memory. There are also several observers added to the AVQueuePlayer. I really can't help it, it's really annoying since the app should be able to play music when the device is locked etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it own my own. It had absolutely nothing to do with the AVQueuePlayer, I overloaded the app with too many graphics, which resulted in over 100% of cpu usage and for the app to be killed, of course the player would stop playing.